# Backbone remove events from previous view

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a trouble probably caused from lack of understanding Backbone's event mechanism.

Either I get *previous events* still attached or *current events* not firing.

1. If I don't use `$('body').off()` or `this.$el.off()` (my target is `body`) obviously everything remains because `Backbone`'s event model attaches & listens to what's propagated on `body`.
2. If I use `$('body').off()` or `this.$el.off()`, in `initialize` method, like this:

   ```
   module.exports = Backbone.View.extend({
       initialize: function(){
           this.KontaktViewTemplate = $.ajax({ url:'index.php/templateget/kontakt', dataType:'text', cache:true});
           this.$el.off();
           this.render();
       },
       render: function(){
           var $el = this.$el;
           this.KontaktViewTemplate.done(function(text){
               $el.html(text);
           });
       },
       events: {
           'click div': "Alert"
       },
       Alert: function(){
           alert('Example');
       }
   });
   ```

**I even don't get `'click div': "Alert"` to work.**

My best guess that events from Backbone's `View` are attached even before `initialize` method is called, thus `.off()` call comes too late and wipes them out.

Should I handle this outside of Backbone?

Comment: You are right: _"events from Backbone's View are attached even before `initialize` method is called"_

Comment: @EmileBergeron thanks. So, do you know about any Backbone-baked way to handle this or should I go outside of Backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone View's events are just namespaced jQuery events ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1402-L1422)).

> ```
> delegate: function(eventName, selector, listener) {
>   this.$el.on(eventName + '.delegateEvents' + this.cid, selector, listener);
>   return this;
> },
> ```

They are delegated inside the [`setElement` function](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1372-L1377)) which is called in [`_ensureElement`](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1449-L1459) before `initialize` in the View's constructor.

If an element is shared with multiple Backbone Views, or if you reuse the same view in multiple place, you could be having problems with the events still attached or doubled.

Say your view is a bare `div` like the default and you want it to use the existing element `<div id="existing"></div>` and that div already has events attached to it.

You'll do something like:

```
view.setElement($('#existing'));
```

`setElement` will first undelegate events from the `view` only. Any events attached elsewhere will still be attached. Then, it delegates events from the `events` view property.

Also, calling [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) ([source](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/blob/7da4ed73e7402baf614a50a6551d47ace68b5239/backbone.js#L1357-L1361)) on a view will explicitly undelegate any events attached to the element.